# Flutter Futurebuilder's future function Gets Halfway Through And Never Finishes The Rest

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, flutter-futurebuilder

This is the problem. The `print` statement in the `populateProviders` function is not getting run.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Future<void> loadData = Future(
    () => null,
  );

  bool hostBottomNavigationBar = true;

  void toggleHostBottomNavigationBar() {
    setState(() {
      hostBottomNavigationBar = !hostBottomNavigationBar;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadData = populateProviders();
  }

  Future<void> populateProviders() async {
    await Provider.of<ExploreData>(context, listen: false).populate();
    await Provider.of<HostEvents>(context, listen: false).populate();
    print('This line never runs');
    return;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: loadData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.connectionState !=
                ConnectionState.done
            ? Scaffold(
                appBar: AppBar(title: Text('House')),
                body: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              )
            : hostBottomNavigationBar
                ? HostScaffold(widget.title, toggleHostBottomNavigationBar)
                : PartierScaffold(widget.title, toggleHostBottomNavigationBar));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in the future function, there was an invalid call to an api, which caused the function to crash halfway through.

Here is the future function in question, stripped down to contain only the invalid api call and some print statements for demonstration.

```
Future<void> populate() async {
    print('This executes');
    var snapshot = await db
        .collection("parties")
        .where(FieldPath.documentId, whereNotIn:)
        .get();
    print('This does not execute');
  }
```

[See here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74310801/async-function-not-completing-when-querying-firebasefirestore?noredirect=1#comment131202189_74310801)

Answer (score 1):

If your statement is not set, loaddata is not set after the page is loaded first. the structure you set up is wrong mate. If you want to set up a more understandable structure, you can try the one below.

Can you delete the **initstate** provider function? and can you delete the function in **loaddata**. Also, if your **populate()** function doesn't have **notifyListeners()**, could you add it?

```
 @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return 
 Consumer2<ExploreData, HostEvents>(
          builder: (
            final BuildContext context,
            final ExploreData exploreData,
            final HostEvents hostEvents,
            final Widget? child,
          ) {
            return 
FutureBuilder(
    future: Future.wait([exploreData.populate(),hostEvents.populate()]),
    builder: (context, snapshot) => snapshot.connectionState !=
            ConnectionState.done
```

Comment: See updated code above. Had to remove notifyListeners() from hostEvent's populate function because it was triggering a build over and over. Now running into a different error, I think your answer was correct but I'm not sure since my code is not yet functioning properly, so I will post a new question here:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74310801/async-function-doesnt-complete-when-querying-firebasefirestore

Comment: I don't think this really helps - it's the same thing as your original code, only now you have a problem of build being called from ExploreData and HostEvents after it notifies listeners. Can you give more details on populateProviders - does it even run (put one print command first?). Does it complete the first call? This would tell you which part of the code hangs. Theny you can explore further.