# async function not completing when querying FirebaseFirestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

See the `print` statement down below. It never executes.

```
  Future<void> populate() async {
    final userId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

    final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    // Get list of ids of parties use swiped on.
    var snapshot1 = await db
        .collection("partiers_swipes")
        .where('userId', isEqualTo: userId)
        .get();

    var partyIdsUserSwipesOn = [];
    if (snapshot1.size > 0) {
      snapshot1.docs.forEach((element) {
        partyIdsUserSwipesOn.add(element.data()['partyId']);
      });
    }

    var snapshot2 = await db
        .collection("parties")
        .where(FieldPath.documentId, whereNotIn: partyIdsUserSwipesOn)
        .get();
    print('This never executes');
  }
```

Comment: Similar to my comment on your linked post: what does execute in this procedure? Can you put print statement before and after each statement to understand if this is called at all - and where does it hang?

Comment: @Andrija everything before `snapshot2` executes

Comment: How many documents you get in snapshot1 and in partyIdsUserSwipesOn ?

Comment: 0 documents in `snapshot1` and 0 items in `partyIdsUserSwipesOn`. `snapshot1.size` == 0. @Andrija

Comment: @Andrija I have the answer. I was passing in a `whereNotIn` argument to the `where` clause, which is not supported by Firebase, so the function stopped executing... and thanks for your time my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `whereNotIn` argument is not supported by the `where` clause. This crashes the function.